# rails encapsulate tags in textfield

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

I would like to know how to implement a textfield for TAGS in ROR?

like the ones used in stack overflow, or at emails where you type a text and after you hit space it capsules it.

I would appreciate any gem or any info about the matter.

example1:

[image: example]

example2:

[image: example]

Thanks

Comment: In general you don't implement it in RoR, you implement it in JS. There are a number of implementations available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at [chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/). 
I.e. give the multi-select example a try.

Add the `"chzn-select"` class to the multi-select requiring the tagging behavior.

And in your javascript, invoke the chosen initialization method, `$(".chzn-select").chosen();`